# How do I make a block spawn when a player dies?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Well, I'm making a trap, and it contains trip wire. And after a player dies, the trip wire disappears. *(It actually burns away because of the lava that comes with the trap.)* I want to trip wire to be replaced after a player dies. How could I do that?

Comment: with command blocks or in survival

Comment: @AMeme I would appreciate if you hit that green checkmark :D

Comment: @AMeme That means the answer solved your problem. So, when other people visit this question, they know that is the answer.

Answer (score 3):

There is only one way of doing this, except of constantly reloading the trap, which is by using Command blocks:

Place Command blocks next to the trap Redstone so that it activated **after** the trap is cleared (use Repeaters). In the CMD blocks place this commands:

> /setblock X Y Z minecraft:tripwire_hook

for the hook, and the following for the wire:

> /setblock X Y Z minecraft_string

Instead of X, Y, Z put the hook's and tripwire's coordinates - for each hook and tripwire a different set of coords.
 I haven't tested this, so the tripwire hook could stick to a different wall - you can try giving the hook a different damage for different rotation (`minecraft:tripwire_hook 1`, `minecraft:tripwire_hook 2`, ...)